# Simpler Method of Unsubscribing from Observable in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx, angular7

I have an implementation, that automatically unsubscribes from Observables when the component is destroyed using `takeUntil`. But it's annoying to implement the same code in many components.

**I want to know if this could be simplified**
(I can't use `async` pipe because I need the emitted values in the Typescript component)

Here is my current implementation:

```
export class Component implements OnDestroy {
    _dstr = new Subject();

    data$: Observable<any> = this.store.select(Selector.getData);

    constructor(
        private store: Store<State>,
    ) {
        this.store.pipe(
            select(Selector.getOtherData),
            takeUntil(this._dstr),
        ).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('here is my data!', data)
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._dstr.next();
        this._dstr.complete();
    }

}
```

Comment: One of the solution is to bind observable to view through async pipe which take cares of automatically unsubscribing.

Comment: If you need the data in your typescript component, and not in the template, then you are not using the component correctly. You should try to never use `subscribe` and let everything be handled by the `async` pipe, and transform the data using the rxjs operators. If you however do need the data, you can always just select it once using `take(1)` or `first()`, which will unsubscribe automatically, because the observable completes immediately

Comment: Try https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-rx-collector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could collect all your subscriptions in an array and unsubscribe each in ngOnDestroy function. If you need this behaviour very often you could consider using an abstract class from which you extend all your components from which does this for you.

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy{
  public subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("destroyed");
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {

}

let count: number = 0;
@Component(
  {
    selector: 'app-derived',
    template: 'Derived Class'
  }
)
export class DerivedComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private store: Observable<any> = of(count++);
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push( this.store.subscribe(data => console.log(data)) );
  }
}
```

Blitzstack demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-peyoac

Comment: That's great! But I am not really why `super()` is needed?

Comment: Any derived class must call the parent constructor. In my short example super is not really needed because it has no arguments. The typescript transpiler till call it under the hood for you. But as soon as you have some arguments in derived class' constructor you will need to call it manually. Otherwise you will receive an error